# How to make a chrome plugin

Tags: plugins, google-chrome

I was curious how to make a chrome plugin that loads some JS on every page - I've seen it done before, but now I want to make my first chrome plugin, one that changes all the fonts on websites to comic sans ms. Yep, this is a prank to pull on friends computers.

I would assume it would take like 4 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416

not really a plugin, however, it will work if you change it to what you want.
I've only tested it on stackoverflow and google.

If you actually want to build an extension
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: Please don't confuse native **plugins** with **extensions**. They are very different things. And this is a very popular mistake polluting google search results.